# Networking at potential future workplace

Tags: postdocs, career-path, networking

I am currently finishing up my PhD, and already have a postdoc position lined up for a few years. Following that, I might like to move to a different country to work there for a few years. Now my question is: I will be visiting this country soon and have some spare time. Would it make any sense to already try to visit the university there? A current colleague might be able to bring me in touch with people there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are any touchpoints between your interests and the university, then absolutely, go for it. If possible, give a presentation on your work. It is almost always better to have a network than not to have a network. Now that you are starting your postdoc phase, you need to find collaborators, and if there are common interests, this sounds like a good place to find them, whether or not you end up there in a few years.

However, this presupposes you do some homework beforehand. Find out what people at that university are working on. When you meet someone who just published something that connects to your work, *be aware of that* and be able to have an intelligent discussion. This shows interest, and will lead to people remembering you better (and in a better way).